# Theorem 2.7.1 of Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic, by Leary and Kristiansen

Tags: logic

Theorem 2.7.1 of Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic states the following:
$$\begin{array} {rl}
\text{1.} & x = x \\
\text{2.} & x = y \to y = x \\
\text{3.} & (x = y \land y = z) \to x = z 
\end{array}$$

The derivation of 2 is the following:

$$[x = y \land x = x] \to [x = x \to y = x] \tag{E3}$$
$$x = x \tag{E1}$$
$$x = y \to y = x \tag{PC}$$

My question is: what is the justification for the last move? How can you apply PC to lines 1 and 2.

Thanks!

Comment: If the last line weren't true you'd need $x=y$ true and $y=x$ false. That would make either 1 or 2 false, since if 2 is true then that and the assumption 3 is false render the lhs  of 1 true and rhs false, thus making 1 false.

Comment: Unless you clarify what E3, E1, PC, etc mean, no one will be able to help you except those who actually own your book (or can make excessive guesses).

Comment: Axiom (E3) is: $(x_1=y_1 \land x_2 = y_2) \to (R(x_1,x_2) \to R(y_1,y_2))$

Comment: Apply it with $x$ as $x_1,x_2$ and $y$ as $y_1$ and $x$ as $y_2$: $(x=y ∧ x=x)→(R(x,x)→R(y,x))$.

Comment: Now use $=$ in place of $R$.

Comment: (PC) rule is defined at page 53.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$PC$ stands for Propositional Consequence ... it is not so much a syntactically/formally defined rule, as it is a rule that allows one to derive any statement $\varphi$ from any other statements $\Gamma$ if $\varphi$ is a propositional logic consequence of $\Gamma$, i.e. if $\varphi$ has to be true if all the statements in $\Gamma$ are true on the basis of the propositional logic operators (like $\land$, $\lor$, $\neg$, and $\rightarrow$) involved in those statements.

In this case, if you assume that $[x = y \land x = x] \to [x = x \to y = x]$ and $x = x$, it must also be true that $x = y \to y = x$, since if $x=y$, then given $x=x$, we have $x=y \land x=x$, and thus given $[x = y \land x = x] \to [x = x \to y = x]$ we must have that $[x = x \to y = x]$, so given $x=x$ we obtain $y=x$. In sum: given the two statements $1.$ and $2.$, we get that if $x=y$, then $y=x$, and therefore $x=y \rightarrow y=x$.

So again, note that $PC$ is not your typical rule that says 'If you have something of the form bla bla bla , then you write down a new statement with the form this and that', but rather is a really powerful rule that allows one to make propositional logic inference without really formally proving them ... which is exactly why it can be hard to always see why something checks out with $PC$.